# Angular2: view is not updated from inside a subscription

Tags: angular

I have a simple angular2 (rc1) component which subscribes to a service. When the service updates the subscription, I can log the result in the component's subscription but the view isn't updated.

My initial suspicion was that my inner `this` wasn't bound to the outer one, but I'm using a fat arrow on the `subscribe` callback, and also tried the old `let self = this` on the first line of the constructor and then doing `self.SuccessMessage = result` to no avail.

Do I have to force the change detection somehow? Here's my component:

```ts
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import {UploaderService} from './uploader.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'aoma-uploader-status-mini',
  providers: [],
  viewProviders: [],
  templateUrl: './app/uploader/mini-uploader-status.component.html'
})
export class MiniUploadStatusComponent {
  subscription:Subscription;
  successMessage:any = {};

  constructor(private _uploaderService: UploaderService) {
    // view correctly shows this value:
    this.successMessage.serverMessage = 'before ';
    this.subscription = _uploaderService.fileSuccess$.subscribe(result => {
        // this fires and logs the result correctly:
        console.log('the mini uploader: type of result', result);
        // view is never updated here
        this.successMessage = result;
      })
  }

}
```

Currently my view only has `{{ successMessage | json }}` in it. Again it correctly displays the 'before' value, but doesn't change when the subscription gets the result object.

Comment: How do you display the message in the template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `_uploaderService` runs outside Angulars zone. Angular won't detect changes when values are changed from outside its zone.

To make the code to run inside the zone use

```ts
  constructor(private _uploaderService: UploaderService, private zone:NgZone) {
    // view correctly shows this value:
    this.successMessage.serverMessage = 'before ';
    this.subscription = _uploaderService.fileSuccess$.subscribe(result => {
        // this fires and logs the result correctly:
        console.log('the mini uploader: type of result', result);
        // view is never updated here

        this.zone.run(() => this.successMessage = result);
      })
  }
```

There are also other ways to notify Angular about changes [Manual Change Detection in AngularJS or Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36231026/manual-change-detection-in-angularjs-or-angular-2)

If there is additional code run like when `router.navigate()` is called outside the zone, only `zone.run(...)` will properly solve the issue - except when there is a way to make your service run inside Angulars zone in the first place.

Comment: If this doesn't help more information is required like the part of your template that shows how you bind to the `successMessage`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I've updated the question to show my template content. Unfortunately zone.run(...) didn't work. I'm thinking I should look into `ChangeDetectionStrategy`? Of course if you have an example that would be great ;-).

Comment: If `zone.run` didn't solve it, the problem is caused by something else. Can you post what `console.log('the mini uploader: type of result', result.json());` prints to the console?

Comment: It prints was I was hoping, which is an object with the server response: `the mini uploader: type of result object Object {file: ResumableFile, serverMessage: "Thank you for uploading to the server."}`

Comment: When you add this to `successMessage` statically, does it show it? It's quite weird. Everything looks fine ...

Comment: thanks. When I set it statically the view did indeed change. In the end, the issue was that the JSON pipe was silently not outputting the object, mostly likely because it contained a FileReader object. Doh! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this solution still valid?

Comment: @DeveshJadon yes, it is