# Angular2/4 changeDectorRef not working

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular-changedetection

I have a navbar component, inside its `ngOnInit` function I have checked if user is logged in or not, if the user is logged in then I change `isAuthorized` to true, and its default is `false`, then I check with `*ngIf="isAuthorized"`, in my menu `li`s.
Now when the user is not logged in some of my menu items are not created, and when the user clicked on the post like button, I have checked to show login modal if the user is not logged in. After user logged in, I can change `isAuthorized` of `navbarComponent` from `false` to `true`, but my navbar component can't detect the changes and create other menus.
Inside login function I have:
`this.navbar.refresh();`
after I have set token, and inside navbar component, I have a refresh function:

```
refresh() {
    this.isAuthorized = true;
    this.changeDetector.detach();
    setInterval(() => {
      this.changeDetector.reattach();
      // if (!this.changeDetector['destroyed']) {
        this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
      // }
      this.changeDetector.detach();

    }, 10000);
  }
```

The main thing I want is to prevent from reloading when a user logged in with modal, and show other menu items.

Comment: Are you inside angular zone?

Comment: Why exactly are you detaching the change detector?

Comment: @TomaszKula just tried to solve this problem, somewhere else suggested this, I have also tried with simply `detectChanges()`

Comment: @yurzui does not understand your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391696/angular-2-what-make-a-service-to-be-outside-angular-zone

Answer (score 0):

change detection isn't your problem since `ngOnInit` gets called only once initiating the `navbarComponent` ..

a highly candidate solution i use, is to define a `Subject<boolean> isLoggedIn` and in the `navbarComponent` you subscribe to it at `ngOnInit`

```
 isLoggedIn.asObservable().subscribe(newVal => isAuthorized = newVal);
```

when the user logs in you push the value `true` like

```
 this.isLoggedIn.next(true);
```

the subscribtion will automatically fire each time `isLoggedIn` changes then `isAuthorized` change also

[here](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject) is a good example of encapsulating this in a service

**Additional Advice**

use localStorage to store the token so a user won't need to enter his credintials each time he refreshes ..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem relate to maintain the state of the application.
We can use `rjxs/BehaviorSubject` to keep the state and we can get rid of `ChangeDetectorRef`

```
// auth.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class AuthState  {
  private auth$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  public login() {
    return this.auth$.next(true);
  }

  public logout() {
    this.auth$.next(false);
  }

  public isLoggedIn() {
    return this.auth$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

In `navbar component` and template

```
constructor(public authState: AuthState) {
  this.authState.isLoggedIn().subscribe((isAuth) => {
    // do something
  }
}
```

In `login component` (somewhere)

```
this.authState.login()
```

Hope this help.

For complex state - management, checkout [@ngrx/platform](https://github.com/ngrx/platform)