# How to retrieve objects from parse platform and show them using Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, parse-server

I want to retrieve an object that stored in parse platform and I'm using ionic framework.
so I wrote this code in **Home.ts** :

```
export class HomePage {
result: string = 'sample' ;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
Parse.serverURL = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/';
Parse.initialize("MY_APP_ID", "MY_JS_KEY");
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);

query.get("wN9bVUA9Hu", {
  success: function(gameScore) {
    // The object was retrieved successfully.
     this.result = gameScore.get("score").toString();
     console.log(this.result);
  },
  error: function(object, error) {
    // The object was not retrieved successfully.
    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
  }
});
}

}
```

and object's id is = wN9bVUA9Hu, so that should retrieve the object's score which is 9.
but as you see here : [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6nth.jpg)

result didn't change in **Home.html** but in the console, it is 9.

here is my **Home.html** code :

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
     <ion-title>
  Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
   <h4>{{result}}</h4>
</ion-content>
```

how can I solve this and show the retrieved object in Home.html ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, this should have been obvious to me but my eyes just slip over these things.

```
var func1 = () => console.log(this.result);
var func2 = function { console.log(this.result); }
```

These two statements are not the same.  Where possible, your sanity will be improved if you use arrow functions (e.g. `func1`).  They are newer to JavaScript so many examples you see will not include them.

In an arrow function `this` points to same object inside the function as it does outside.  With the `function` syntax `this` is reassigned to something else depending on how it was called.  So in your code, when you say `this.result = gameScore.get("score").toString();` the problem is that `this` is not referencing the instance of `HomePage`.

If you need to keep the `function` syntax (a few libraries rely on reassignment of `this`) then you have to do something like...

```
const self = this;
query.get("wN9bVUA9Hu", {
  success: function(gameScore) {
     self.result = gameScore.get("score").toString();
  },
  error: function(object, error) {
    // The object was not retrieved successfully.
    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular wraps a number of the default input and output events (e.g. button clicks, http requests, etc.) inside of zones.  This way, Angular knows when something happens, and it knows that since something happened it may need to update bindings.

However, some libraries (as it appears parse is doing here) will issue events that Angular hasn't wrapped and doesn't know about and so code can end up running outside of a zone.  To fix this, you can manually put the code back into a zone.

Try changing:

```
  success: function(gameScore) {
    // The object was retrieved successfully.
     this.result = gameScore.get("score").toString();
     console.log(this.result);
  },
```

To be:

```
  success: function(gameScore) {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.result = gameScore.get("score").toString();
      console.log(this.result);
    });
  },
```

You will need to add `private zone: NgZone` to your constructor and `import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';` to import `NgZone`.

Further Reading:

[Angular 2 : what make a service to be "Outside" angular zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391696/angular-2-what-make-a-service-to-be-outside-angular-zone)

[Triggering change detection manually in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-change-detection-manually-in-angular)

https://medium.com/@MertzAlertz/what-the-hell-is-zone-js-and-why-is-it-in-my-angular-2-6ff28bcf943e

Comment: I did this but it said: Property 'zone' is declared but its value is never read.

Comment: and also in console logged nothing

Comment: I can't understand what's going on but I think your solution is true and I tried it in various ways, But it has not worked yet...

Comment: Can you add the full file for one of your attempts?  Maybe on StackBlitz or something?

Comment: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-s2qbae?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.ts)